# How to apply albedo, ambient occlusion, normal/bump maps and metalic/roughness texture for Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, node-editor, normal-map

I have a model with multiple maps : albedo, ambient occulusion,metalic,roughness and normal map. I only managed to add the normal map to the mesh in Cycles. I want to apply the others too but don't know how

[image: Photo reference]

How would I go about applying the other maps in Cycles ? I couldn't find any reference on YoUTube or Google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to do is use the Principled Shader node! It has dedicated slots for all of those maps, except for ambient occlusion. Albedo is the same as base color. To use your ambient occlusion, in this case, multiply it with your albedo map before plugging it into the base color. You can either do it in the node editor with a mixRGB node (one of the dropdown options is multiply), or externally in an image editor.

Here's an image of what you probably should have in the node editor so that you can apply all of your textures onto the mesh. I got this screenshot from Blender Guru's [tutorial on Principled Shader](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4H5W6C_Mbck) in Blender:

[image]

(In addition, make sure you have a Texture Coordinate node, found in 'input' under the 'add' menu, and hook up your UV slot to your texture maps.)