# Where should the different downloadable texture maps plug into

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor

[image]I am downloading textures from online and I have found where to plug most of the on a principled shader from online.
There is a map called mask, and after further research I am unsure what this does or how to apply it through a principled shader.

To be clear: I am still unsure that textures the mask would be mixing, as a mask doesn’t seem to be applicable to the other textures.

Textures downloaded from cc0 textures

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120623/how-to-apply-albedo-ambient-occlusion-normal-bump-maps-and-metalic-roughness-t/120627#120627 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55232/how-to-properly-hook-up-various-maps-types-together-in-cycles/95090#95090

Comment: Thank you for your response, I now know how to use all maps accept mask. Do you have any idea on what the "mask" map could be used for?

Comment: perhaps show some screenshots of your blend file so that we guess?

Comment: There is a picture showing the _mask map that I am unsure about

Comment: Masks allow you to control a mix. Usually is conntected Fac socket of a mix node, to control the mix of colors (RGB), or the mix of different shaders . That is what allows you to say: only parts of this texture will be X and the rest will be Y.

Comment: the mask-texture can be used for materials were different shader are mixed and with the mask you can define where which part object has what shader

Comment: Thank you that makes perfect sense. Do you know anything that might indicate which textures are intended to be mixed with the mask?